# Webpack: Duplicate content found in multiple entry file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Glob file

```
const entryArray = glob.sync('src/**/*.js');
const entryObject = entryArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const name = item
  acc[name] = "./"+item;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Webpack Config

```
const browserConfig = {
  entry: entryObject,

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name]",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
}
```

> { 'src/App.js': './src/App.js',   'src/App.test.js':
>   './src/App.test.js',   'src/index.js': './src/index.js',
>   'src/page/About.js': './src/page/About.js',   'src/page/Home.js':
>   './src/page/Home.js',   'src/serviceWorker.js':
>   './src/serviceWorker.js',   'src/setupTests.js': './src/setupTests.js'
>   }

I am able to get multiple files in build folder. But the problem is contents of Home.js is found in index.js and App.js. As all files are linked to index through import and all files in pages are link to App.js.

What I want is I don't want duplicate copy but all bundles are linked to each other through the import. May be you can say it code splitting.

Answer (score 2):

Glob file

```
const entryArray = glob.sync('src/**/*.js');
const entryObject = entryArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const name = item
  acc[name] = "./"+item;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Webpack Config

```
const browserConfig = {
  entry: entryObject,

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name]",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
  },
}
```

This will keep the structure which you want, and not have the duplicate data. Instead this will create another file which will be shared internally between several files. This way you can avoid code duplication as well as ensure your bundles are loaded faster. Bonus once the shared file is loaded by any of your file, next time another bundle which depends on the shared file will just use the browser cached file. This makes your code super efficient with the bundle size and over the network as well.

And yes, this is possible in nextjs.

Comment: Still not working! It seems to i have to use dynamic import else i have to create a webpack plugin to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

`SplitChunksPlugin` may help for code deduplication

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
      },
    },
  };
```

and you can use the approach below for dynamic imports and linking libraries

```
  module.exports = {
    entry: {
      index: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
      publicPath: 'build/',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    }
  };
```

but this lacks very basic best practices needed for React. I suggest you to take a look simple tutorials like [This](https://maksimivanov.com/posts/basic-webpack-react-setup/)